# SQL - Selecting columns based on attributes of the column

Tags: sql, database-design

I am currently designing a SQL database to house a large amount of biological data.  The main table has over 100 columns, where each row is a particular sampling event and each column is a species name.  Values are the number of individuals found of that species for that sampling event.

Often, I would like to aggregate species together based on their taxonomy.  For example: suppose Sp1, Sp2, and Sp3 belong to Family1; Sp4, Sp5, and Sp6 belong to Family2; and Family1 and Family2 belong to Class1.  How do I structure the database so I can simply query a particular Family or Class, instead of listing 100+ columns each time?

My first thought was to create a second table that lists the attributes of each column from the first table.  Such that the primary key in the second table corresponded to the column headers in table 1, and the columns in table 2 are the categories I would want to select by (such as Family, Feeding type, life stage, etc.).  However, I'm not sure how to write a query that can join tables in such a way.

I'm a newbie to SQL, and am not sure if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way.  How can I structure my data/write queries to accomplish my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question! With SQL it's better to expand the amount of rows you are using in order to leverage its querying power. @Gordon Linoff's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, no, no.  Don't make species columns in the table.

Instead, where you have one row now, you want multiple rows.  It would have columns such as:

- id:   auto generated sequential number
- sampleId:  whatever each row in the current table belongs to
- speciesId:  reference to the `species` table
- columns of data for that species on that sampling

The `species` table could then have a hierarchy, the entire hierarchy with genus, family, order, and so on.